# Permissions needed by dircolors

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to use a custom ~/.dir_colors file to set custom terminal colors. I've got the `eval` in my `.bashrc` file and everything, but when `dircolors` is used with the file option, it does not change the value of LS_COLORS, even when I run it with `sudo`.

For example:

```
dircolors ~/.dir_colors
```

Outputs:

```
LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=07;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:*.cpp=00;36:';
export LS_COLORS
```

The first (very long) line assigns LS_COLORS to match the settings in my .dir_colors file. The second line is meant to export the new LS_COLORS. Pretty straightforward, but after the command is executed, `echo $LS_COLORS` shows that `LS_COLORS` has not actually been changed. Does `dircolors` need some extra permissions or something to modify `LS_COLORS`? I can modify it myself using `export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:<stuff to add>`, but escaping the semicolons in the format flags is a pain, and `dircolors` is supposed to do this automatically. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** As @Alexandre Beaulieu's answer points out, `dircolors` does not execute anything, it just outputs strings that can be executed as commands using `eval`, or placed in a script. Another problem I encountered was with the default .bashrc file in Ubuntu 14.04. It was looking for a file in my home directory called .dircolors, instead of .dir_colors, as I've seen in every documentation, to pass to `dircolors`. Editing that to look for .dir_colors, or renaming .dir_colors to .dircolors will make the settings be applied automatically at login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dircolors doesn't execute the commands itself, it just outputs the commands to be executed. Passing them to eval will work.

Try this:

```
eval $(dircolors ~/.dir_colors)
```

Comment: Oohhh!! That makes much more sense! Thank you! Is this in the documentation somewhere? Or is it some kind of standard behaviour- do you know of other tools that rely on `eval` this way? (And welcome to Ask Ubuntu- I see this is your first answer here!)

Comment: It is documented in the standard help (--help) and man page that dircolors output commands. However, to get the example usage with eval documentation, you'd have to run (as stated in the man page): info coreutils 'dircolors invocation'

Comment: It's uncommon for UNIX tools to output commands to be passed to a shell eval. Actually, dircolors is the only tool I know that does this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstood what I was reading in the --help and the manpage. I was also having the problem I edited in just now, which thickened the confusion. Thank you.